# Where to storage docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, git-submodules

I am a backend developer. And I have many projects that keep the same docker-compose.yml and service folder.

When I create a new project, I transfer them to the new project. The errors in this are obvious.
Can you please tell me what is a good practice for this? Move docker files to git submodule?

Comment: Hey, what are the obvious errors in that? What problem are you facing?

Comment: repetitive manual actions and versioning problem.
I would like there to be some kind of unified environment where it is worth switching only versions of images as needed

Comment: Could you share your project folder structure? (You can get it using the `tree` command.)

Comment: Provide more details , like errors that you're facing when moving projects~

Comment: @claudius

1. docker
 - nginx
 - php-fpm
2. docker-compose.yml
3. .env
4. .env.example
5. .git/
6. README.md
6. src/